# dropdown multi with same value but different datatype

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am developing a `dash` app. I have a `dropdown` with `multi` that contains different datatype value. In this set of values, I have value as 1 which is `str` type and 1 which is `int` type. I am able to select both, but **problem** is when I remove any of them both gets removed.

**my observation is** If I am able to select both values distinctly, then It must remove the respective type.

```
import dash
from dash import Dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

dbc_css = (
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AnnMarieW/dash-bootstrap-templates@V1.0.2/dbc.min.css"
)

app = Dash(
    __name__,
    suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, dbc_css],
)

div_one = html.Div(id="div_one")

options = ["Montreal", "Paris", "1", "#99", 1]
value = ["Paris", "Montreal"]

dd = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="dd",
    options=options,
    value=value,   
    multi=True,
)

@app.callback(
    Output("div_one", "children"),
    Input("dd", "value"),
)
def process(val):
    print(f"{val=} and {type(val)=}")
    
    for v in val:
        print(f"{v=} and {type(v)=}")

    return val


app.layout = dbc.Container(html.Div([dd, div_one]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8001", debug=True)
```

What I am missing?

Comment: This happens because on the clientside, in the field where selected items appear, both "1" and 1 are represented as "1" (without the quote obviously, ie. all items are strings), even if when selecting them from the options dash recognize which option (int vs string) is selected and trigger the callback with the proper value and type (which means a quick fix in the js part of Dash is possible), the front end code get confused and only sees numeric strings which are automatically converted from and back to number. In fact, users will have the same problem for distinguishing the 1 from the "1".

Comment: You could quote the numerical strings to let the code and users distinguish the difference between them, ie. `options = ["Montreal", "Paris", "'1'", "#99", 1]`

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks. I tried using extra single quotes, it is working.Yes, handling this in dash `js` is good options but I am not good at `js`, but this adding/removing single quotes is manageable.